# Unity replace sign in string with text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have default JSON file with some text.

Here is one line of the json file

```
    "description": "this will add X dollars to your account"
```

After I read all content of json file and convert it to object(I know how to do this) in my game I want to replace X with some int value, and my new sting should be

```
int doll = 50;

sting desc = "this will add 50 dollars to your account";
```

It should be very simple but I new to c#

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use numbered placeholders that string.Format() uses instead of X.

```
var myString = "this will add {0} dollars to your account"; 

myString = string.Format(myString, 50);
```

Or multiple:

```
var myString = "This will add {0} dollars to your account number {1}.";

myString = string.Format(myString, 50, "N012345");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Replace` method if you want to replace all instances of one string with another:

```
string desc = description.Replace("X", doll.ToString());
```